# Convert AD date to Date and then search for specific dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a specific date format for  RESV_CENTER_Date column in my table which is difficult to understand and i need to search data for specific months. I am unable to search using Cast-it gives me an error saying. I have pasted a record to understand that date format. I want to see it in a Date format as the arrival or departure date.

```
***conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.***

s_id    ARRIVAL_DATE    DEPARTURE_DATE  RESV_CENTER_Date
06385   [2017/06/16]    [2017/11/17]    [2017.11.17 AD at 10:23:08 GMT]
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: The problem is these are  **NOT** dates. They are strings pretending to be dates. You'll do much better if you can _fix_ the table (because it really is _broken_ right now) to store actual datetime values instead of a strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates don't have formats... that means you stored it as a `varchar`, which is apparent by the `at` word in your string.

You want only the *date* portion... `replace(right(left(RESV_Center_date,11),10),'.','/')`

Here is it in action:

```
declare @RESV_CENTER_Date varchar(64) = '[2017.11.17 AD at 10:23:08 GMT]'
select replace(right(left(@RESV_CENTER_Date,11),10),'.','/')

--or if the brackets aren't there

set @RESV_CENTER_Date = '2017.11.17 AD at 10:23:08 GMT'
select replace(left(@RESV_CENTER_Date,10),'.','/')
```

So for your `where` clause... which isn't SARGable...

```
where cast(replace(right(left(RESV_CENTER_Date,11),10),'.','/') as date) between  '2017-05-05' and '2017-06-06'
```

Comment: How do i search for specific dates using this command for RESV_CENTER_Date between '2017-05-05' and '2017-06-06'?

Comment: Gotcha. But in Declare you have specified a fixed date? why is that?

Comment: it was to show the working code with sample data... the last line i used your actual column name so you can copy and paste.

Comment: you are genius sir. Thanks a lot!